# Flash Player scripting + IE8

Tags: javascript, flash

I've developed a small control bar for a Flash viewer generated by a third-party software. It has a First, Prev, Next & Last button, and a Zoom command.

While Zoom works fine in all browsers, the navigation buttons seem to fail at Internet Explorer 8.

I use at least two functions. This one locates the Flash object I want to manipulate:

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName)
{
  if (window.document[movieName])
  {
      return window.document[movieName];
  }
  if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
  {
    if (document.embeds && document.embeds[movieName])
      return document.embeds[movieName];
  }
  else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
  {
    return document.getElementById(movieName);
  }
}
```

...and any of these ones handles the frame navigation:

```
var currentFrame = 0;
function gotoFirst(id)
{
    getFlashMovieObject(id + "Blueprints").Rewind();
    currentFrame = 0;

    $("currentFrame").innerHTML = currentFrame + 1;
    $("frameTitle").innerHTML = frameTitles[id][currentFrame];
}

function gotoPrev(id)
{
    var movie = getFlashMovieObject(id + "Blueprints");
    if (currentFrame > 0)
    {
        currentFrame--;
    }
    movie.GotoFrame(currentFrame);
    $("currentFrame").innerHTML = currentFrame + 1;
    $("frameTitle").innerHTML = frameTitles[id][currentFrame];
}

function gotoNext(id)
{
    var movie = getFlashMovieObject(id + "Blueprints");
    if (currentFrame < movie.TotalFrames() - 1)
    {
        currentFrame++;
    }
    movie.GotoFrame(currentFrame);
    $("currentFrame").innerHTML = currentFrame + 1;
    $("frameTitle").innerHTML = frameTitles[id][currentFrame];
}

function gotoLast(id)
{
    var movie = getFlashMovieObject(id + "Blueprints");
    currentFrame = movie.TotalFrames() - 1;
    movie.GotoFrame(currentFrame);
    $("currentFrame").innerHTML = currentFrame + 1;
    $("frameTitle").innerHTML = frameTitles[id][currentFrame];
}
```

Btw, that $ is MooTools, not jQuery.

Anyway, IE dies on the `movie.TotalFrames()` call. What can I do to solve this? Keep in mind I *need* this to be done via JavaScript, as I cannot edit the SWF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing this code:

```
if (currentFrame < movie.TotalFrames() - 1)
```

with this

```
if (currentFrame < movie.TGetProperty('/', 5) - 1)
```

It's not as nice, but is another option.  `TotalFrames()` should work.